# Div contents won't update - Simple Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to code a function that'll change the contents of a div to "Too short" -- the replacement string will be altered later -- when an input that is too short is entered; however, once it's been updated the div contents on the page doesn't change.
I verified that it has actually changed by "alerting", the alert changes to the new contents of the div but the div doesn't visibly change and remains the same.
Here are the extracts of code.

Javascript:

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById('xxx').innerHTML;
    function xxxx(xx) {
        if (xx.value.length < 6) {
            x="Too Short";
            alert(x)
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input onBlur="xxxx(this)" placeholder="*****"><div id="xxx">
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the value to the `innerHTML`-*property*:

```
x="Too Short";
alert(x)
```

must be:

```
x.innerHTML = "Too Short";
alert(x.innerHTML);
```

It is because `x` contains the DOM-element, and you shouldn't overwrite it.

You should just change its properties, for example: `innerHTML`, or `style.color`, and so on..

Comment: i added the innerhtml value to the X variable... and i comfirmed it is actually changing the value by alerting the contents of the div.

Comment: @WorstForum. Just be sure you typed `innerHTML` with case sensitive (upper and lower case letters)

Comment: ohh i get it, when i change x to too short it competely removes the contents of x and changes to "too short"  not changing the contents of the div to too short

Comment: Yeah, you got it ;) ... If this answer worked for you, you can accept it checking the [green mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/318874).

Comment: tried that before you asked but it said i have to wait a few more minutes

Comment: @WorstForum. Something else I noted now: `x` must be equal just `document.getElementById('xxx')` without the `.innerHTML`.. the other answer has pointed this out.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be look like this:

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById('xxx'); // need to get element, not its innerHTML
    function xxxx(xx) {
        if (xx.value.length < 6) {
            x.innerHTML = "Too Short"; // set innerHTML of element to change its content
            alert(x.innerHTML); // show HTML of x element in modal window
        }
    }
</script>
```